# How do I extract the generics of a function?

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to create a HoF that infers the generics of the function it receives as arguments as its own.

The function looks roughly like so:

```js
import * as t from 'runtypes';
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const db = new Pool({
    max: process.env.DB_MAX_POOL_SIZE,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    connectionTimeoutMillis: process.env.DB_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MS,
});

export const query = async <T>(validator: t.Runtype<T>, actions: string): Promise<T> => {
    const results = await db.query(actions);
    return validator.check(results.rows);
}
```

And the HoF looks like so:

```js
export const measure = <Func extends (...args: any[]) => any>(func: Func) => (...args: Parameters<Func>): ReturnType<Func> => {
    const then = Date.now();

    try {
        return func(...args);
    } finally {
        console.log(Date.now() - then);
    }
}
```

And I would like to infer the generic parameters of `query` so that when I do

```js
import * as t from 'runtypes';
import { query } from './query';
import { measure } from './measure';

(async () => {
    const measuredQuery = measure(query);
    const result = await measuredQuery(
        t.Record({ entry: t.String }),
        'SELECT entry FROM database'
    );

    console.log(result);
})();
```

The result will be of type `{ entry: string }` (as in, `measuredQuery` takes the generic from the query function) instead of `Promise<unknown>`.

I tried doing something like so in order to extract the generic parameters:

```js
type Extract<Func> = Func extends <infer Generics>(...args: any[]) => any ? Generics : never;
```

But sadly the syntax is not valid.

Comment: Could you edit this code to form a [mcve] without dependencies on external/undeclared types/values like `RunType`, `t`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some [support for higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions), but it is heuristic in nature and it only happens in certain circumstances.  Instead of having a single type parameter `F` corresponding to the whole function, you'll have a better time with two type parameters corresponding to the argument list `A` and the return type `R`:

```
const measure = <A extends any[], R>(func: (...a: A) => R) => (...args: A): R => {
  const then = Date.now();
  try {
    return func(...args);
  } finally {
    console.log(Date.now() - then);
  }
}
```

This compiles, and you'll see that when you pass in a generic function, the returned function is now also generic:

```
const someGenericFunction = <T, U>(t: T, u: U): [T, U] => [t, u]
// const someGenericFunction: <T, U>(t: T, u: U) => [T, U]

const measured = measure(someGenericFunction);
// const measured: <T, U>(t: T, u: U) => [T, U]

console.log(measured(1, "hello")[1].toUpperCase()) // 0, "HELLO"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgLYFMCGMCuAnFCC8CAPAIIIoAecKUAJjAmlAJ4DaAugDQIBKAfAAoAZpihgAXAgEA6WWkkkAlAT69l+VTLnYA5jAWLJPFQgDeoBAkixEcABY0CCACJpq0qBADuAxQG4LBDhsZjNAy1w4HCgEETEtaTRdGH9AgF9YgEsoNAAbXNDzEEtLaxgIXJRpXIgdAVd3Tx9lAFoghyhU4oQ00F6QUDLEctQAcRoUbEywADFRMDhM6CciABVuAFVBOEl1hExJDcMEVj2N9hNWOG5MdlAAenuraHgEEZRxqEnpubFF6Eka02212N0O6lUp02dwG4BeiFQGBwKFoTkRWFwAnen2+s3m-06ARAj2eNmQ6AxKMBZxBCD2BwQR0uZxhgxeFSqNTq6ORtAEAEZuAAiBz5CBCxSsfnsaRwCAbAAOCsmAGEMChfMoSQAGYUACQAogAZI0AeSFoFAQA)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly. Thank you!